# React Native FlatList Rerender Problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have this selection FlatList where the user can select a country. When I press on a item it's going to take a second and after the second it is displaying the checkmark.

The Problem is the second. The user cannot wait a second to see that the country was selected.

```
<FlatList
  keyExtractor={item => item.countryid}
  data={countryChoices}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    return(
      <CountryComponent                                       
        item={item}
        conditionToCheck={country == item.countryname}
        onPress={() => setCountry(item.countryname)}
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

This is my Flatlist. `countryChoices` is just an array with different objects for the countries. the `conditionToCheck` checks wether to show or to hide the checkmark. If the selected Country is equal to the item then it's going to show the checkmark.

But after clicking on it it's taking too long :/

I also tried wrapping the FlatList Item in a useCallback but it wasn't (much) faster

[image]

Comment: country == item.countryname aka country === item.countryname

Comment: Implement update verification to your components. React's PureComponent implement a shouldComponentUpdate with shallow comparison. This is expensive here because it needs to check all your props. If you want a good bit-level performance, create the strictest rules for your list item components, checking only props that could potentially change. https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `country` as `extraData` in you FlatList since `country` is outside of `data` prop

```
<FlatList
  keyExtractor={item => item.countryid}
  data={countryChoices}
  extraData={country}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    return(
      <CountryComponent                                       
        item={item}
        conditionToCheck={country == item.countryname}
        onPress={() => setCountry(item.countryname)}
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

[extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) is a marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements `PureComponent`). If any of your `renderItem`, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the `data` prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

Comment: Sadly there is no performance boost. The delay is still there

Comment: Oho ok then can you make it sure that if this happens in dev mode only? take an release apk and check if it works smooth. Sometimes in dev mode there may see lag to rerender